# Python get return values of a function separately

Tags: function

I have a simple function in python. Is it an easy way to get result_1 and result_2 in separate lists? thanks

```
def add(x, y):
    result_1 = x + y
    result_2 = x*y
    return result_1, result_2
```

for example for x=5, y=6
something like

```
 result_1=[11]
 result_2=[30]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do somthing like this to separate the return in 2 variables:

```
result_1, result_2 = add(5,6)
```

and if you want it to be inside a list follow @dc914337 answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would need two lists with single elements but you can define whatever return format you want. I e you can create 2 lists using your results:

```
def add(x, y):
    result_1 = x + y
    result_2 = x*y
    return [result_1], [result_2]
```

This will return 2 lists, each consisting of a single element.

Comment: ok thanks, I ahve amore complicated function so that's why I need it thanks!